# Can't pass a string argument into a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

When I try to run my program it prints out

> "error: no matching function for call to `Dog::Dog(const char [4], const char [5])`".

This occurs at line 60 and 61. Is it reading the arguments as a C-String? I should still be able to pass it into the constructor, can't I?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include <string>
class Pet
{
protected:
    string type;
    string name;
public:
    Pet(const string& arg1, const string& arg2);
    virtual void whoAmI() const;
    virtual string speak() const = 0;
};

Pet::Pet(const string& arg1, const string& arg2): type(arg1), name(arg2)


{}
void Pet::whoAmI() const
{
    cout << "I am an excellent " << type << " and you may refer to me as " << name << endl;
}

class Dog : public Pet
{
public:
    void whoAmI() const;  // override the describe() function
    string speak();

};

string Dog::speak()
{
    return "Arf!";
}

class Cat : public Pet
{
   string speak();
    // Do not override the whoAmI() function
};

string Cat::speak()
{
    return "Meow!";
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Pet& p)
{
    p.whoAmI();
    out << "I say " << p.speak();
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Dog spot("dog","Spot");
    Cat socks("cat","Socks");
    Pet* ptr = &spot;
    cout << *ptr << endl;
    ptr = &socks;
    cout << *ptr << endl;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: does C++ [insert version here] "inherit constructors"?

Comment: There is more wrong with the code than the lack of constructors for Dog and Cat. Voted to reopen.

Comment: https://ideone.com/XptrrQ should do

Answer (score 0):

`Pet` has constructor taking 2 string, not `Dog`.

You might use Base constructor thanks to using (since C++11):

```
class Dog : public Pet
{
public:
    using Pet::Pet;

    void whoAmI() const;  // override the describe() function
    string speak();
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/GNDRPz)

Comment: There is more stuff wrong than the "constructor inheritance".

Comment: @AdrianoMartins: Indeed, there is also wrong `override` because of constness.